# Querying VIVO data using SPARQL endpoint

Tags: rdf, sparql

My current data is to fetch some data from VIVO. I found some existed VIVO endpoints of some universities like:

- http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/sparql/
- http://vivo-onto.slis.indiana.edu/SPARQL/

Here's a personal page of a researcher, generated by VIVO:

- http://reach.suny.edu/display/Alonso_Jose-Manuel

How could I try to query this researcher's publications by the SPARQL endpoints? What shall I put as the URIs in the SPARQL queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explore the endpoint a bit, by using some general queries and eyeballing the result, to figure out the general "shape" of the data.

First query I did (on the first endpoint you provided) was a simple query to see what classes are available:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {[] a ?Concept}
```

Browsing through the result I saw that they apparently use the `foaf:Person` class, which seems a likely candidate to find people in. So, second query, see what instances of class `foaf:Person` look like:

```
SELECT * WHERE {?x a foaf:Person; ?p ?y } ORDER BY ?x LIMIT 100
```

This retrieves all instances `?x` person, and for each instance its properties (`?p`) and the values of those properties (`?y`). I order on `?x` to have all results for the same person together, and I limit to 100 because I only need to see a small subset of all results (after all, I'm only exploring the shape).

Looking at that data I see that people typically have a `foaf:firstName` and `foaf:lastName` property with a string-value, and also that they have a `rdfs:label` property which has the full "firstname, lastname" string as a language-tagged literal. So to retrieve specific individuals, I can query on those properties to get the individual's URI, e.g.:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE {?x a foaf:Person; foaf:lastName "Alonso"; ?p ?y} LIMIT 10
```

or

```
SELECT ?x WHERE {?x a foaf:Person; rdfs:label "Alonso, Jose-Manuel"@en-us . } LIMIT 10
```

Of course, we can also actually look at the value of `?x` which is typically of the form:

http://reach.suny.edu/individual/Alonso_Jose-Manuel

If you actually follow that link in a browser it will redirect you to the page  http://reach.suny.edu/display/Alonso_Jose-Manuel you asked about. So another way to query for that particular individual is to take the URL of his webpage, replace the `display` with `individual`, and use that as the subject-URI in your SPARQL query.

Comment: Hi Jeen thanks for your detailed explanation. I get your idea. and I had a try, but met some problem. I put the question below, is it possible for you to take a look?Thanks!